# Disable page elements of webpage using overlay?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

**SOLVED**

Okay. You won't believe this but the "pointer-events" element in the CSS file messed everything up. In the "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" file I just had to change hideOnOverlayClick and hideOnContentClick from "true" to "false". I mean I did do that from the start but the "pointer-events" was interfering so the page objects were still clickable.

What a waste of a day all because of "pointer-events". My brain is too tired.

**-----**

I am using the FancyBox pack for one feature on my website.

When you add a product to your cart, a popup window appears which states what you have ordered and the quantity.

Using firebug, I've determined the overlay is"#fancybox-overlay". I found this in the CSS files and used "pointer-events:none", which is working. However, if you scroll over a button or the main menu, you are still able to interact with those objects.

So if the user adds an item to the cart, and then clicks on the "addtocart-button" for another item, it will add the item to the cart. I just need the webpage objects to be disabled, until they physically press the "Close" button for the small popup.

I've delved into this file: "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" which is where you can change some things. I was thinking of adding an onclick event to the "addtocart" button, so that when the "#fancybox-overlay" is open due to the click on the addtocart button, it must disable webpage objects and elements.

The whole background must be disabled upon clicking the addtocart button. I've tried z-indexes, using a transparent image as a cover; nothing is working.

Something I had in mind:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
if $('.addtocart-button').click==true){
    $('#fancybox-overlay') {backdrop: static, keyboard: false}

}


});
</script>
```

Comment: Hard for anyone to help without a [mcve]

Comment: That's true. Sorry about that. Just that it's mostly a JS pack with a lot of lines and characters. I'll try and set something up

Comment: Create a fixed div that's `100vh` and `100vw` and only display it once the modal is open. In my example the modal is pure CSS but this will work with JS modals as well. The name of the class I gave to the overlay is `.overlay` and I used z-index stacking to wedge it behind the modal but on top of the content. https://jsfiddle.net/9g4ywvod/.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man. Will give it a go and update with the results

Comment: Happy to help, but please bear in mind that this a workaround at best and any user can bypass it using browser console

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Ihazkode just to let you know I solved it and won't be needing to use the workaround. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, you can post what worked for you as the answer and accept it.